# the incrementAge function is returning undefined/NaN when invoked after defining the new User

Tags: javascript

sorry, the incrementAge function is returning undefined/NaN when invoked after defining the new User. I am not sure what's wrong

```js
function User(name,age){
this.name = name;
this.age = age;
}

User.prototype.incrementAge = ()=>{
return this.age++;
}

const mike = new User("Mike",20);
console.log(mike.incrementAge());
```

Comment: Don't use arrow functions for pseudo-OO. Either use `function` only (https://jsfiddle.net/wsamxtpq/) or write a proper ES6 `class`.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisG. I am not sure why it is but using function () { } instead of ()=>{ } resolved the issue.

Comment: @Jevex Some [details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-interchangeable) about your question

Comment: Thanks @Sergey, I am just going through that answer now. Thank you for the link.

Comment: The arrow function made `this` refer to `window` so `this.age` was `window.age` i.e. `undefined`. And adding one to that results in NaN.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this is to create a User class and create a method to raise the value of the variable age.

As you can see by calling the increment age method several times the value is added.

```js
class User {
  constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }

  incrementAge() {
    return ++this.age;
  }
}

const mike = new User("Mike", 20);

console.log(mike.incrementAge());
console.log(mike.incrementAge());
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution (by @ChrisG in comments)

```js
function User(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}

User.prototype.incrementAge = function () {
  return ++this.age;
}

const mike = new User("Mike", 20);
console.log(mike.incrementAge());
```